# Rank-2 types in data constructors

Tags: gadt, higher-rank-types, purescript

I've been trying to encode GADTs in PureScript using rank-2 types, as described [here](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/gadts.html) for Haskell

My code looks like:

```
data Z
data S n

data List a n 
  = Nil (Z -> n)
  | Cons forall m. a (List a m) (S m -> n)

fw :: forall f a. (Functor f) => (forall b . (a -> b) -> f b) -> f a
fw f = f id

bw :: forall f a. (Functor f) => f a -> (forall b . (a -> b) -> f b)
bw x f = map f x

nil :: forall a. List a Z
nil = fw Nil

cons :: forall a n. a -> List a (S n)
cons a as = fw (Cons a as)


instance listFunctor :: Functor (List a) where
    map f (Nil k) = Nil (f <<< k)
    map f (Cons x xs k) = Cons x xs (f <<< k)
```

The compiler complains `Wrong number of arguments to constructor Main.Cons`, referring to the LHS pattern match in the Functor instance.

What is going wrong here?

Regards,

Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax used for existential types in Haskell is not present in PureScript. What you've written for `Cons` is a data constructor with a single universally-quantified argument.

You might like to try using `purescript-exists` to encode the existential type instead.

Another option is to use a final-tagless encoding of the GADT:

```
class Listy l where
  nil :: forall a. l Z a
  cons :: forall a n. a -> l n a -> l (S n) a
```

You can write terms for any valid `Listy` instance:

```
myList :: forall l. (Listy l) => l (S (S Z)) Int
myList = cons 1 (cons 2 nil)
```

and interpret them by writing instances

```
newtype Length n a = Length Int

instance lengthListy :: Listy Length where
  nil = Length 0
  cons _ (Length n) = Length (n + 1)

newtype AsList n a = AsList (List a)

instance asListListy :: Listy AsList where
  nil = AsList Nil
  cons x (AsList xs) = AsList (Cons x xs)
```

Comment: Thanks for this Phil - I was after a way to represent the initial encoding so will definitely take a look at purescript-exists.

Comment: I think you'll want actual type equalities, not just functions then. `Nil (absurd :: Z -> S Z) :: List a (S Z)` is a bad term right now.